# Can't add item in Postgres using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to use Postgres with Django application.
I am using pgAdmin to manage Postgres database.
But I can't add new item to database using pgAdmin manually.
Once I typed data manually and clicked the save button, I got

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: "111"
LINE 3: '111'::uuid, 'asdfasdfdasf'::character varying)
        ^
```

Schema is just simple.
Just id and name in the table.
Please help me to fix the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: `111` is not a valid value for `uuid`.

Comment: Works as designed: Your table requires a valid UUID and you try to insert an integer. That should fail and it does fail.

Comment: You forgot to share the query you are running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a default auto-generated value for your id field with the following commands:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

 ALTER TABLE public.table_name
  ALTER COLUMN "id" SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

After that, you need to populate only the name column.

Comment: Since Postgres 13 this is not necessary any more. It [provides such a function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html)  (But the absence of such a function is not the problem the OP is facing anyways)